# Test if a point is on a broken ellipse

Tags: c#, geometry

I have a "broken" ellipse:

[image]

Lets say if I represent this ellipse in the parametric form:

```
x = h + a cos (t)
y = k + b sin (t)
```

and that I know the t values of the points that are cut off `(t1, t2)`

How do I test if a point lies on this ellipse? (meaning if the point lies on the cut-off region, it is not considered true)

Rearranging the equation, I have tried using `acos(x)` method but it doesn't work as it does not cover more than PI. Using `atan2(x,y)` to solve for t doesn't work too as there may be a singularity at `t = 90 degrees`.

Comment: You know that this has nothing to do with C# or any other language?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to do this in the .NET framework.

Comment: The solution for the problem wouldn't change from you using .NET Framework or any other framework. Your question is incomplete because you didn't say how your "broken ellipse" is represented. Set of points? Image? Parametric curve?

Comment: There is no singularity with atan2 at 90 degrees. This function was intended to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ellipse however you want to, (I believe c# has supported shapes) and test if it is on the ellipse. If so, then test to see if it is on the good side of a line drawn between those two points at the given y value. You didn't give us code to work with so that's the best we can do.